# Redirect page to existing page from and unknown page route in Next JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, next.js

I want to redirect an incoming request path to a different destination path.

Next.Js provides a way to do it using [redirects](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects)

```
module.exports = {
  async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/fr/recherche',
        destination: '/search',
        permanent: true,
      },
    ];
  },
};
```

Now, is there any way to do it without creating a page with '/fr/search' route in pages folder?

Comment: The solution you proposed doesn't require you to have a page at `pages/fr/search`. `/fr/recherche` will be redirected to the path that matches your `pages/search` page.

Comment: @juliomalves : In that case, we would have to create a file name 'recherche' in pages directory otherwise its throwing 404